# I need help retrieving sub arrays from JSON with a HIVE query

Tags: arrays, json, hadoop, explode, azure-hdinsight

I have the following JSON.

```
{
    "_id": "00075602-f58d-49f5-8a82-9b5fb5582443",
    "ActivityCountedCollection": [{
        "Lesson": "98d66ab9-1ef4-4b61-a05d-857b3e07e0f8",
        "DataSet": 1,
        "DateTime": "2013-06-19T15:54:27.79+00:00",
        "ElapsedSeconds": 0.0000
    },
    {
        "Lesson": "Kindergarten - Play & Practice",
        "DataSet": 0,
        "DateTime": "2014-01-01T00:00:00",
        "ElapsedSeconds": 0.0,
        "Scores": [{
            "DataSet": 11,
            "Lesson": "c241ab4b-3d11-4aca-bb9b-a8a645c1e6ca",
            "ActivityNode": "ef2d4aae-08ad-48eb-a2e3-0ab616ef2e9c",
            "DateTime": "2013-07-01T15:31:11.81+00:00",
            "NumPossible": 2,
            "NumCorrect": 1,
            "Mastered": false
        },
        {
            "DataSet": 1,
            "Lesson": "01d6691f-911f-45b5-b861-778c725b4d98",
            "ActivityNode": "a2783eb1-873d-4ae7-bd58-6ab4bf48692c",
            "DateTime": "2013-07-08T15:09:54.61+00:00",
            "NumPossible": 5,
            "NumCorrect": 5,
            "Mastered": false
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to retrieve the _ID value, along with any scores values within the ActivityCountedCollection. Some docs have scores, some do not.

So lets say that my resultant table would be like this :

```
  _ID,
  Lesson,
  DateTime,
  NumPossible,
  NumCorrect
```

I can retrieve the scores array as a string, by creating the following table and loading it with said json.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $ActivityCounted (
      id string,
      ActivityCountedcollection array<struct<
        Scores:array<string>
        >
      >
    )
```

But i would like to then retrieve the actual fields from within the scores array. I have tried loading the scores into a table as a string, then exploding them again, but believe that since it doesnt know that they are individual fields, and live in a string field, they cant be retrieved.
So i tried recreating the table to include the sub array.

```
 CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $ActivityCounted (
      id string,
      ActivityCountedcollection array<struct<
        Scores:array<struct<
          Skill:string,
          Lesson:string,
          DateTime:timestamp,
          NumPossible:int,
          NumCorrect:int,
          Mastered:string
          > >
        >
      >
    )
```

But this does not work either.

I had another example that was not an complex array of fields, and I was able to extract it to a table, stick the array into a table, then explode that table again, and extracted individual values. But to explode again and extract multiple fields from the array, i am stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have determined the code necessary to produce the results in this request